# How to use BusyIndicator Flex Android App?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I am currently developing an application using the Flashbuilder 4.5 framework and I am having trouble using the BusyIndicator. I have tried setting its visible property in order to show it when an action is being perform(as shown below) however this has not worked. Does anyone know how to work with the BusyIndicator in a Flex Android App????

```
busy.setStyle("visible", true);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this `busy.visible = true;`